# EditText won't wrap its text

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

I know there are lots of related questions in Stackoverflow, but I tried to do everything that's written in any of them and so far I couldn't get this working.

My problem is simple. I have an android application, and I have a box where the user will input text. However, I don't want this text to be multiline (it shouldn't have "\n" in it), but I want it to wrap if the size of the line is greater than the viewport. So basically, what I want is the same behaviour that the textBox on Gmail Subject field has.

This is my whole view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:textAppearance="@style/titleFont"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_question_value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine|textEmailSubject"
    android:maxLength="70"
        >

</EditText>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/answer"
        android:textAppearance="@style/titleFont"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_question_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_question"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/save"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_edit_question"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/cancel"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The text I want to have this behaviour is theone with the id equals to @+id/edit_question_value. So far, I have been able to either make it truly multiline (so the user can type enter if he wants) or single-line and the text won't wrap. Perhaps some of the elements around the text are having some interference, and that's why I included the whole view.

Does anyone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that has bothered a lot of people before and I couldn't find an answer when I needed it. In pure XML, that is. If we can use programming and not just markup, we can do this with a little *hack* if you may. Basically, we are declaring a multiLine editText and then catching the return key to avoid new lines.

First the declaration in **xml**:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noReturnEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:text="lorem ipsum \n dolor site amet helping stackoverflow" />
```

Yes, I know what you're thinking "But hey, *Juan* this is a multiliner `EditText` and I want a one liner like on the subject area of gmail". I know, I know, but we are going to take care of it right now, by removing the behavior of the multiline part we don't want, while keeping the text wrapping we **do** want.

Now the rest of the **code**:

```
EditText noReturnEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noReturnEditText);
         noReturnEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
```

You can probably read the code quite easily, but in case someone needs an explanation, we are setting an `OnKeyListener` to the `EditText` we want to be "oneline-multilinelike" and if the user presses the return key (KEYCODE_ENTER) we tell the event not to propagate by returning `true` which in this context means we've handled the event.

**Result:**

[image]

**Considerations**

Pressing the return key is not the only way of entering a new line. The user could copy/paste some text and end up with a multi-line entry on a single-line EditText. Worry not! We can strip the value before we store it or use it with something like

`myData = rawText.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ");`

**What if I have lots of `EditText` views?**

Well, you basically have two options. Do it one by one and pull your eyes out **or** do something like this, its listing the views and looping for each view.

```
//Declare the reusable listener
  OnKeyListener myListener = new OnKeyListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }  
//Loop through the views
    int viewIds[] = {R.id.edittext1,R.id.edittext2,R.id.edittext3,R.id.edittext4};
    for(int id : viewIds) ((EditText)findViewById).setOnKeyListener(myListener);
```

Comment: what if the user want's to create a checklist line by line ? you block this option ...

Comment: You are commenting on a 6+ year old answer, I made it a community so feel free to improve upon it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/color_red"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:lines="10"
            android:maxWidth="200dp"
            android:maxLength="200"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="26sp" />
```

try this. worked for me when i changed gravity to top|left